# Getting no response calling API using axios in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm quite new to React and I'm trying to get a response from weatherapi.com. However I haven't been very successful. The following is my code snippet:

```
const api_call = async () => {
    const url = 'https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=' + API_KEY + '&q=Singapore'
    const request = axios.get(url)
    const response = await request
    console.log('url - ' + url)
    console.log('request - ' + request)
    console.log('response - ' + response)
}
useEffect(() => {
    api_call()
}, [])
```

the console log that was printed (i had to redact the API Key) :

```
url - https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=xxxxxxxxxx&q=Singapore 
request - [object Promise] 
response - [object Object]
```

I went to the link next generated, and it did show the data I want in the browser.

My axios version is 0.21.1 if it helps.

Now, I want the response to be printed in the console just so I can make sure that I actually got the response. Did I miss something? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request` and `response` are objects. Passing a `string + object` to console.log will cast the object to a string.
So if you want to print the content of the object, you should use `console.log` like this

```js
console.log('response -', response)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   const api_call = async () => {
    try {
      const url =
        "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=" +
        API_KEY +
        "&q=United States";
      const request = await axios.get(url);
      console.log(request.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message, "+", err.code);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    api_call();
  }, []);
```

you needed to access the data object from the axios request, you shouldn't have to stringify the response like you stated below

Answer (score 0):

This was a bad question. What happened was not that I got no response, but that the response wasn't a string (it was a JSON).

I used JSON.stringify() to turn it into string.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are getting the **response successfully**, but the problem is how you are writing it on console.

```
console.log('response -' + response)
```

In above console.log, the response object will be convert to a string(since you are trying to concatenate it with a string), so that is the reason you are seeing that **[object object]** on console.

**Instead use:**

```
console.log('response -', response);
```

This will give the value of response correctly on console.(Including url, data, status etc)

**If you just want data, then use:**

```
console.log('response -', response.data)
```